# Unload some codes if method is not

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code for getting the method of payment, if it is stripe it gonna load stripe data but if not I want it to unload stripe data and make the html button doing submit normally

The html - php code

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

                    <form id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url('payments/redirect_to_paypal');?>" method="POST">
                            <select class="form-control" id="method" name="Payment-Method">
                            <option value="paypal">Paypal</option>
                            <option value="stripe">Credit Card</option>
                        </select>
```

The Jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#method').on('change',function(){
                var method = $(this).val();
                if(method){
                    if(method == "stripe"){
                        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                            key: 'pk_test_8YUupmrOHjstnsJ5S7hufFzG',
                            image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
                            token: function(token) {
                                $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
                                $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
                                $("#amountInCents").val(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100));
                                $("#myForm").submit();
                            }
                        });

                        $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
                            var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);
                            var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                            // Open Checkout with further options
                            handler.open({
                                name: 'شحن رصيدك',
                                description: 'شحن رصيدك بقيمة ($' + displayAmount + ')',
                                amount: amountInCents,
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        // Close Checkout on page navigation
                        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                            handler.close();
                        });
                    }else{
                        // unload the upper one

                    }
                }
            });     
    });
```

I want to unload the upper code that is using for stripe if the method is not stripe

Comment: What is `#method`?

Comment: the method of payment which maybe paypal - stripe or any other method

Comment: I'm asking you to show the relevant HTML.

Comment: I've updated it see now

Comment: Show the rendered HTML only.

Comment: see now if it is okay !

Comment: Why are you adding an event listener inside an event listener?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your code properly and what do you mean with "unload the code" but if you want the form to be submitted on method change, on the else block you should just call to $("#myForm").submit();

Comment: If the user select method stripe it gonna do that events like e.preventDefault(); for customButton, so the button become died , now if the user select another method and use the button it gonna doing nothing! I want it to back normally and submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question exactly, you can't "unload some code", you must write the code you want to execute at any of the possible cases. If there are some pieces of code you want to share or execute always, you could put them after the if-else block or inside an external function that you can call whenever you need it.

If I understand what you want to do properly, I think you should just use the button click handler where you can check the method with $('#method').val() and do the logic you need before form submission.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way available to make the  button default again ?